# Why isn't bundle install working for my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, bundler

I am trudging through the ruby on rails tutorial (so I'm quite ignorant), and I seem to be having a problem with the bundler.  Originally, "bundle install" worked fine, but now I am getting this:

```
C:\Users\Me\RonR\first_app>bundle install
C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:926:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem bundler (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:244:in `activate_dep'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:236:in `activate'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1307:in `gem'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/bundle:18:in `<main>'
```

I tried following a suggestion in another thread to do "gem install bundler", but that itself produces the following:

```
C:\Users\Me\RonR\first_app>gem install bundler
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.2/bin/bundle.bat
```

I've tried searching around, but I am so incredibly new to all of this that, sometimes, I can't even tell if someone else's problem is the same as mine.  Please let me know if there's any more pertinent information that I need to supply.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install bundler (`gem install bundler`) after either using an admin command prompt, changing the permissions of `C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.2` to allow your user to write to it, or changing the Ruby 1.9.2 installation path to someplace that is writable (such as `c:\ruby-1.9.2`)

Comment: The second one option is strongly preferred. You will have a bad time if you install ruby to a path with spaces in it. Maybe not right away, but in the long run...

Comment: I knew that was true in the past, but I haven't used Ruby on Windows in a few years, so I didn't know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are running the command in an account that does not have privilege. Try:

```
sudo gem install bundler
```

Comment: As this is obviously windows, `sudo` won't help here.